# Folders protection in PHP

Tags: php, directory-structure

What is better way for folders protection in PHP? for example in folder `views` I have file `index.php` and if go on this addres: `mysite.com/views/` opened file and I dont want this.

My idea is rename `index.php` as other name, for example `indexx.php` and now if in `.htaccess` write `Options -Indexes` this helps, because causes `403 error`

But... there are better way?

Comment: It has become a common practice to place a folder called "public" or something like that into your application directory and put the entry script (i.e. the index.php) and assets in it. Any other application implementation goes outside the public directory. Set this directory to be your document root and you're done.

Comment: normally views or controller folders are outside of the web root.

Comment: @Daniel and if open this addres: `mysite.com/public/views/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move your MVC folders one level up from the public directory.
2. Add to each folder index.html file with the next content:

   **No direct access allowed.**
3. Start all your contoller and model files with the next line and define SOMECONSTANT in your index.php (init.php or whatever your using):

   ```
   if ( ! defined('SOMECONSTANT')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   ```